# How to compile box2d with Monogame in visual studio 2012?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, box2d, xna-4.0, monogame

I am trying to create a game for windows 8 using Monogame that uses a 2d physics engine. I found a port of `Box2d` to XNA but when I open the solution in visual studio 2012 I get a message saying

> Windows is not a supported platform in this version of XNA Game Studio, or this edition of Visual Studio.

I started writing some code for the game and would like to add a physics library. Does anyone have any suggestions how to accomplish this with `Box2d` or another XNA physics engine?

Comment: Maybe this will help too https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples/tree/master/FarseerSamples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get Farseer Physics working with MonoGame. It wasn't too difficult but I did have to recompile it from source replacing the XNA references with MonoGame.

I believe it's very similar to Box2D.

http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/

Sorry, I don't have a more detailed tutorial to point you too.